# Ability to Virtualize or Use Android Phone as Joystick?

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm hoping to create a virtual joystick or use my android phone as a joystick so that I don't need the physical joystick to be with me at all times, but couldn't figure out how to do so online. In particular, the app I'm creating reads out of the buttons and axes. Are there any suggestions? I am using ROS indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228624/ability-to-virtualize-or-use-android-phone-as-joystick?/) by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(note: I'm not the author of this, don't know if/how it works, and just found it using a 'random' Google search)

For a non-ROS solution: apparently there are tools that can do this. See [droidpad](https://www.digitalsquid.co.uk/droidpad/) fi (Github repository [here](https://github.com/w-shackleton/droidpad-pc)). It's a bit unclear, but if this creates an actual joystick device under Linux (uses `uinput`, so potentially it should/could), it should work just like any other joystick, and you'd be able to use the regular [joy](http://wiki.ros.org/joy) node(s) and everything else that works with Linux joysticks.

A different approach is taken with the various Android 'teleop' applications, which connect to a remote ROS node graph and directly publish `geometry_msgs/Twist` and associated messages. An example would be [com.github.rosjava.android_apps.teleop.indigo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.rosjava.android_apps.teleop.indigo) (playstore link).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpit_Patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55805/arpit_patel/) on 2020-07-26**:
Playstore link is not working.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-27**:
I would be surprised if it did, seeing as this is a question from over 4 years ago ..